# CodeIgniter: form action in nested view

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have a little problem with codeigniter and form.

I'm, working on a project, where security is very important. I use codeigniter and bootstrap.
I have main view, which includes navbar and some other html. In that main view i have `<div id="change">` which i am changing via button group. With those buttons I am calling functions in controller which contains `$this->load->view('pages/something', $data);` When i press on one of those buttons `<div id="change">` is changed and in it, a view, is shown and link is not changed, so main view remains as it is.
But when one of those buttons is pressed, view with form is shown. In it i use `form_open('controller/function', $attributes);`. 
Problem is, that when i submit this form, link is changed and main view is not on screen anymore.

How can i achieve, that when i will submit form, all that will be changed is just `<div id="change">` and not whole site.

I know i am bad in English, sorry. I appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: thanks for all answers. I will test and accept them tomorrow. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit the form with AJAX, here's a basic example with jQuery:

```
// this is the id of the form
$("#idForm").submit(function() {

    var url = "path/to/your/script"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data) {
             // 'data' is the response from the php script.
             // Update <div id="change"> here.
        }
    });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form. (This stops the URL changing).
});
```

Example modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960586/1734864).

Answer (score 1):

You want to refresh PART of the page and not the WHOLE page ? Maybe you need AJAX.

also, to make the link not changed, you have to change

```
config/routes.php
```

like this :

```
$routes['controller/method'] = "your link";
```

read [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) .

Hope it helps